# Is there a method to send HttpWebRequest to download all url's and handles all exceptions?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am working on a `MultiThreadingDownloader` over Http. So I have to work using `HttpWebRequest` to get partial requests. The application is working good for almost all URLs. But sometimes, when trying to get response it throws exception or works wrong (e.g *`ContentLength` returns -1*, *TSL/SSL secure exception*, *cookie-required links*)

I have not enough knowledge about client-server relationship, so I can't handle all exceptions.

I am using currently this method:

```
public static HttpWebRequest SendRequest(string url) 
{
   HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
   req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
   req.Accept = "*/*";
   req.Method = "GET";
   req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
   req.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 8;
   req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
   req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

   return req;
}
```

What should an `HttpWebRequest` contain to get the `HttpWebResponse` successfully for all URL sources? My method is not working for all as I said. A detailed documentation or code block for the method can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The server is at liberty to not provide a content length. This is useful for streaming data. Here, you can't do much about it. You can't support segmented downloads for such URLs. There is no way to discover this situation other than *trying*.

It's the same thing with HTTPS and cookies. The server is free to reply with anything that it wants and require any input that it likes.

You will need to handle all these cases specially. They are allowed by the HTTP protocol. `HttpWebRequest` does not have much built-in to help you. The only helpful features in this regard are following redirects and decompression. This is default-on so you probably did not even notice it's there.

Comment: So, how can I know what does the server require to reply my request succesfully?

Comment: You can't since it's arbitrary code. You could ask the user or just try.